# fgetcsv output not appearing

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I'm working on a one-off, single-purpose CSV format conversion script. I'm taking a file from one provider and mapping its fields to the format of another provider.

So far, I have a CSV file that I want to run through a PHP script that will
1. Strip out the header line
2. Put the CSV data into an array
3. Print the contents of the first field in the array (so I can see it's working)

The CSV file looks like this sample:

```
Order Date (UTC Time Zone),Order Number,Customer Name,Customer Address,Customer Address2,City,State,Zip,Country,Product Name,Quantity,UPC,SKU,Shipping Carrier,Tracking Number
2017-10-09,1000-000001-000001,John Doe,1234 ANY DR,"",ANY CITY,CA,90210,US,ACME® Product,1,012345678910,012345678,"",""
```

The problem is that my script, below, prints out nothing. I simply want to verify that I have an array and that the data it contains is landing in the right array index.

```
<?php 
// Remove headers from the first line of file "yyyymmdd.csv" and save it to an outfile named "yyyymmdd_clean.csv"
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
$original = fopen("20171010.csv", "r");
$first = fgets($original,2048); #get first line.
$outfile="20171010_clean.csv";
$o = fopen($outfile,"w");
while (!feof($original)) {
    $buffer = fgets($original,2048);
    // Save outfile
    fwrite($o,$buffer);
}
// Close original file, but don't close outfile
fclose($original);

// Convert cleaned outfile into array of SourceLine[n],SourceField[n]
while (($data = fgetcsv($o)) !== FALSE) {
    echo "OrderID " . $data[0];
}
// Now close the outfile. We're done.
fclose($o);
?>
```

I'm running it on a remote development server.

What do I need to change to make it echo the first field of the data to the screen?

Comment: You need to [rewind()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php) the output file pointer, because it's at the end of the file

Comment: You're also opening it in "write only" mode, not "read/write" mode; you need `"w+"`, not simply `"w"`

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) stated, the problem was that I hadn't used `rewind()` and I wasn't opening it in read/write mode (`w+`).